# problem in loading css and js files in django project

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

can anyone pls help in loading and linking html css and js files so that files can be show on local host server when i run django project  im newbie if anybody can help i can email them  code so they can make corrections i tried almost more than 26 hours trying to solve it but cant  i provided my codes here if anyone want to contact they can contact me on my email or msg or can drop their ids ill send them code

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from final import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.homepage),
    path('aboutUS/',views.aboutUS),
    path('course/<int:courseid>',views.courseDetail),
]
```

**setting.py**

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'final.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR,"templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'final.wsgi.application'
...
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR,"static"
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def homepage(request):

    return render(request,"index.html")

def aboutUS(request):

    return HttpResponse("welcome to baljinder shop")
    
def courseDetail(request,courseid):

    return HttpResponse("courseid")
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="font-size: 16px;" lang="en"><head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="70%, off all">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nicepage.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css" media="screen">
    <script class="u-script" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" defer=""></script>
    <script class="u-script" type="text/javascript" src="nicepage.js" defer=""></script>
    <meta name="generator" content="Nicepage 4.14.1, nicepage.com">
    <link id="u-theme-google-font" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i|Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i">
    <link id="u-page-google-font" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:200,300,400,500,600,700">
    
    
    
    <script type="application/ld+json">{
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "",
        "logo": "images/default-logo.png"
}</script>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#478ac9">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Home">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  </head>
  <body data-home-page="Home.html" data-home-page-title="Home" class="u-body u-xl-mode" data-lang="en"><header class="u-clearfix u-header u-header" id="sec-d8dc"><div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1">
        <a href="https://nicepage.com" class="u-image u-logo u-image-1">
          <img src="images/default-logo.png" class="u-logo-image u-logo-image-1">
        </a>
        <nav class="u-menu u-menu-dropdown u-offcanvas u-menu-1">
          <div class="menu-collapse" style="font-size: 1rem; letter-spacing: 0px;">
            <a class="u-button-style u-custom-left-right-menu-spacing u-custom-padding-bottom u-custom-top-bottom-menu-spacing u-nav-link u-text-active-palette-1-base u-text-hover-palette-2-base" href="#">
              <svg class="u-svg-link" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#menu-hamburger"></use></svg>
              <svg class="u-svg-content" version="1.1" id="menu-hamburger" viewBox="0 0 16 16" x="0px" y="0px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><rect y="1" width="16" height="2"></rect><rect y="7" width="16" height="2"></rect><rect y="13" width="16" height="2"></rect>
</g></svg>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="u-nav-container">
            <ul class="u-nav u-unstyled u-nav-1"><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-palette-1-base u-text-hover-palette-2-base" href="Home.html" style="padding: 10px 20px;">Home</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-palette-1-base u-text-hover-palette-2-base" href="About.html" style="padding: 10px 20px;">About</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-palette-1-base u-text-hover-palette-2-base" href="Contact.html" style="padding: 10px 20px;">Contact</a>
</li></ul>
          </div>
          <div class="u-nav-container-collapse">
            <div class="u-black u-container-style u-inner-container-layout u-opacity u-opacity-95 u-sidenav">
              <div class="u-inner-container-layout u-sidenav-overflow">
                <div class="u-menu-close"></div>
                <ul class="u-align-center u-nav u-popupmenu-items u-unstyled u-nav-2"><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="Home.html">Home</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="About.html">About</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
</li></ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-black u-menu-overlay u-opacity u-opacity-70"></div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div></header>
    <section class="u-clearfix u-image u-valign-bottom-md u-section-1" id="carousel_f298">
      <div class="u-palette-3-base u-shape u-shape-circle u-shape-1"></div>
      <div class="u-clearfix u-gutter-0 u-layout-wrap u-layout-wrap-1">
        <div class="u-layout">
          <div class="u-layout-row">
            <div class="u-align-right u-container-style u-layout-cell u-right-cell u-shape-rectangle u-size-26 u-layout-cell-1">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-valign-top u-container-layout-1">
                <h3 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-1">last chance</h3>
                <h1 class="u-custom-font u-font-oswald u-text u-text-2">70%<br>
                </h1>
                <h2 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-3">off all</h2>
                <p class="u-text u-text-default u-text-4">image from <a href="https://www.freepik.com/photos/background" class="u-active-none u-border-1 u-border-black u-btn u-button-link u-button-style u-hover-none u-none u-text-body-color u-btn-1">Freepik</a>
                </p>
                <a href="https://nicepage.online" class="u-btn u-button-style u-hover-palette-1-dark-1 u-palette-3-base u-btn-2">start now</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-border-no-bottom u-border-no-left u-border-no-right u-border-no-top u-container-style u-expand-resize u-image u-layout-cell u-left-cell u-size-34 u-image-1" src="">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-2"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="u-clearfix u-section-2" id="sec-9a88">
      <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1"><span class="u-icon u-icon-1"><svg class="u-svg-link" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" viewBox="0 0 52.966 52.966" style=""><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-54a4"></use></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" xml:space="preserve" class="u-svg-content" viewBox="0 0 52.966 52.966" x="0px" y="0px" id="svg-54a4" style="enable-background:new 0 0 52.966 52.966;"><circle style="fill:#57ABC1;" cx="21.983" cy="21" r="20"></circle><line style="fill:none;stroke:#556080;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;" x1="35.437" y1="35.798" x2="50.983" y2="51.966"></line><path style="fill:#7CCBD8;" d="M3.002,27.253c0.848,2.582,2.24,5.018,4.167,7.146L35.382,6.186
    c-2.129-1.928-4.564-3.319-7.146-4.167L3.002,27.253z"></path><path style="fill:#556080;" d="M21.983,42c-11.58,0-21-9.42-21-21s9.42-21,21-21s21,9.42,21,21S33.562,42,21.983,42z M21.983,2
    c-10.477,0-19,8.523-19,19s8.523,19,19,19s19-8.523,19-19S32.459,2,21.983,2z"></path></svg></span>
      </div>
    </section>
    
    
    <footer class="u-align-center u-clearfix u-footer u-grey-80 u-footer" id="sec-976f"><div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1">
        <p class="u-small-text u-text u-text-variant u-text-1">Sample text. Click to select the Text Element.</p>
      </div></footer>
    <section class="u-backlink u-clearfix u-grey-80">
      <a class="u-link" href="https://nicepage.com/website-templates" target="_blank">
        <span>Website Templates</span>
      </a>
      <p class="u-text">
        <span>created with</span>
      </p>
      <a class="u-link" href="" target="_blank">
        <span>Website Builder Software</span>
      </a>. 
    </section>
  
</body></html>
```

css

```
 .u-section-1 {
  background-image: url("images/3275a3b2-bcc5-9a4f-f817-c88abc58def1.jpg");
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  min-height: 603px;
}

.u-section-1 .u-shape-1 {
  width: 228px;
  height: 228px;
  margin: 50px auto 0 calc(((100% - 1140px) / 2));
}

.u-section-1 .u-layout-wrap-1 {
  width: calc(((100% - 1140px) / 2) + 1068px);
  margin: -278px 0 0 auto;
}

.u-section-1 .u-layout-cell-1 {
  min-height: 603px;
}

.u-section-1 .u-container-layout-1 {
  padding: 60px 30px;
}

.u-section-1 .u-text-1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}

.u-section-1 .u-text-2 {
  font-size: 12.5rem;
  line-height: 0.8;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 20px 0 0 auto;
}

.u-section-1 .u-text-3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 17px 0 0 auto;
}

.u-section-1 .u-text-4 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 auto;
}

.u-section-1 .u-btn-1 {
  border-style: none none solid;
  padding: 0;
}

.u-section-1 .u-btn-2 {
  border-style: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-image: none;
  margin: 20px 0 20px auto;
}

.u-section-1 .u-image-1 {
  min-height: 603px;
  background-image: url("images/0488e092-b70c-9c90-3aec-eb3f7ff03e09.jpg");
  background-position: 50% 100%;
}

.u-section-1 .u-container-layout-2 {
  padding: 60px;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
   .u-section-1 {
    min-height: 425px;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-shape-1 {
    margin-left: calc(((100% - 940px) / 2));
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-layout-wrap-1 {
    width: calc(((100% - 940px) / 2) + 899px);
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-layout-cell-1 {
    min-height: 545px;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-text-2 {
    font-size: 10.625rem;
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-btn-2 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-image-1 {
    min-height: 545px;
    background-position: 74.43% 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
   .u-section-1 {
    min-height: 439px;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-shape-1 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-layout-wrap-1 {
    width: calc(((100% - 720px) / 2) + 701px);
    margin-top: -243px;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-layout-cell-1 {
    min-height: 100px;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-container-layout-1 {
    padding-top: 55px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-text-2 {
    font-size: 7.8125rem;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-image-1 {
    min-height: 407px;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-container-layout-2 {
    padding: 30px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
   .u-section-1 {
    min-height: 945px;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-shape-1 {
    margin-top: 26px;
    margin-left: calc(((100% - 540px) / 2));
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-layout-wrap-1 {
    width: 504px;
    margin-top: -235px;
    margin-right: calc(((100% - 540px) / 2));
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-container-layout-1 {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-text-2 {
    font-size: 12.5rem;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-image-1 {
    min-height: 539px;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-container-layout-2 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
   .u-section-1 {
    min-height: 777px;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-shape-1 {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: calc(((100% - 340px) / 2));
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-layout-wrap-1 {
    width: 307px;
    margin-top: -158px;
    margin-right: calc(((100% - 340px) / 2));
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-layout-cell-1 {
    min-height: 349px;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-container-layout-1 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-text-2 {
    font-size: 6.875rem;
    width: auto;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-text-3 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  .u-section-1 .u-image-1 {
    min-height: 318px;
  }
}.u-section-2 .u-sheet-1 {
  min-height: 500px;
}

.u-section-2 .u-icon-1 {
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  margin: 29px 255px 60px auto;
  padding: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .u-section-2 .u-icon-1 {
    margin-right: 195px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .u-section-2 .u-icon-1 {
    margin-right: 146px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .u-section-2 .u-icon-1 {
    margin-right: 92px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not python dev, but it is a common problem. Client will also make a request to the server whenever meets script:src and link:css. Just send the appropriate files when you receive such request, their pathname are usually smth like /pathto/script.js